# Is there any doc on how accounts are generated in substrate?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

{"address":"5CVVapxEBkvGnK2t1xMd2rbg2P1EekRnNNzPZPWFxwpzcJbv",**"encoded":"0xbf3c994369b9d481cb42e25e7a4e39961ef40c0c60d1bb0d6bcf589bbff62d69961c5c9baeca0c2c884c2fff6fea48665e24652d7c8078e505338ded954e41e2453f37937d4afbf84573178f511ae5b84e903ff989f852b70c967ddddbd223a7fd1985a25690cdd632521e45049ec882ca4ca01caf5691d4fd0fdc6375e1b3d74146e5ed9d40de4b32f35757d8685642ed6db0cabfd49b1bc09b369624"**,"encoding":{"content":["pkcs8","ed25519"],"type":"xsalsa20-poly1305","version":"2"},"meta":{"name":"aravind","tags":["a"],"whenCreated":1637583415090}}

This is one of the account file downloaded from substrate.... What is key-value pair encoded denotes above??
are there any docs on how accounts are created on substrate??(detailed docs)

Answer (score 0):

First, this is **not** *substrate*, it is polkadot-js-extension and appsd .

About the substrate aspect see: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/ss58.

About polkadot-js-extension:

- the `encoded` is your private key, encrypted with your provided password. The rest of the filed are pretty self-explanatory.
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-generation#storing-your-accounts-json-file
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-restore